# Methods of solving linear DEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am very much a beginner to this subject. I have recently learnt the method of integrating factors for solving first order linear differential equations. However, I realised it doesn't really that well in all cases. This morning, I encountered the differential equation: $\frac{dy}{dx} -(1+\frac{3}{x})y = x + 2$. Using the method of integrating factors, I obtained $\ e^{-x}x^{-3}$ as the integrating factor. I then got stuck at the next step as I had to evaluate a seemingly nontrivial integral: $\int e^{-x}x^{-3}(x+2) dx$.

My friend advised me to use the method of finding complementary function and then finding the particular integral, which is typically used for nonhomogeneous 2nd order linear differential equations. The suggested method worked well and produced the desired solution: Firstly, we solve the homogenous DE $\frac{dy}{dx} -(1+\frac{3}{x})y = 0$ and then proceed to find the particular solution by making a guess of the form $\ A + Bx$.

In most learning materials I have seen, the method of finding complementary function and particular integral is not used to solve 1st order linear DEs. I am wondering why that is the case. In practice, the method of finding complementary function and particular integrals should be able to work for most questions that are solved by the method of integrating factors, right?

Comment: The method of homogeneous and then complementary solutions is valid for all linear ODEs, theoretically.  However, for higher order ODEs, it's only practical in general if you have constant coefficients.  Also, the integrating factor method will only work in general for first order odes.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you memorise these two general formulas: $$\int e^x (f(x)+f’(x))dx=e^xf(x) +c$$ and $$\int e^{-x}(f’(x)-f(x))dx = e^{-x}f(x)+c$$ where c is the integration constant. You can verify this by differentiating both sides with respect to x.
Now , $$\int e^{-x} \left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x^3}\right)dx=-\frac{e^{-x}}{x^2}+c$$. (Take $\frac{1}{x^2} = f(x)$).

Comment: If you want to derive them, take the first term of the integral and perform IBP, first integrating the exponential. The second part of the integral will automatically cancel.

Comment: Thank you! The formulae you have shown here are simple but yet will be very useful for solving differential equations.

Comment: @TanYongBoon if you are satisfied that this answer  is very useful and are sure that you won’t need any more answers to this question, then I would suggest you to accept this answer by clicking the checkmark on the top left side of the answer so that this question can be removed from the unanswered list. But if you would like to wait for more helpful / better answers, then you are extremely welcome to do so.